# merge 3 csv files with their data in different columns

Tags: perl, bash, shell, awk

Hi I have 3 csv files with different type of data in all, also no of rows is different in all the files. I want to merge them into a single csv file but when using "paste command data is being copied into output.csv but getting copied to next row not in different column.

file1.csv

```
CELBU,398
ORICE,1026
JSCUN,134250
BHARA,66
MOBTE,2041
RMO,65081
```

file2.csv

```
8/22/2013,1417196108
8/23/2013,1370586883
8/24/2013,1362561606
```

file3.csv

```
ISBND,9 
BHARH,25
```

Desired output:

```
CELBU,398,8/22/2013,1417196108,ISBND,9
ORICE,1026,8/23/2013,1370586883,BHARH,25
JSCUN,134250,8/24/2013,1362561606
BHARA,66
MOBTE,2041
RMO,65081
```

Tried:

```
paste -d"," file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv > output.csv
```

Please suggest is this problem can be solved through perl or shell script.

Comment: What result did you expect? What did you get instead? Show some examples please

Comment: Please provide evidence. The command you're using should do what you said you want.

Comment: ok let me explain. each csv file has 2 columns but no. of rows are different.

csv1:- 2 columns and 362 rows.

csv2:- 2 columns and 8 rows

csv3:- 2 columns and 337 rows

*** the output file should contain data of all 3 csv in different columns that means total no of columns should be 6.

Comment: Could you put this explanation, with *example*, into the question please? It seems like you want data kept completely separate in the new file, with file 3 ending up in rows 371 to 707 and columns 5 and 6 (assuming first item numbered 1)? Do the input files have column headers?

Comment: none of the files have columns headers. lookk files are too big its hard for me to give an example. can we move this conversation to chat ?

Comment: lets take in this way------
file 1:- CELBU 398
file 2:- 8/22/2013 1417196108
file 3:- MOROM 105092112
***Note: please consider spaces as"," as these are csv files. and each file has diff no. of rows but two columns each.

Comment: OK, it's a start. I put it into the question for you. What is your expected output for that input?

Comment: Neil, output should be data of all three files in a single file so out put file should have 6 columns like first 2 columns of file 1 then first two columns of file 2 nd then first two columns of file 3. no appending from next row means all in different columns. 3 files 2 columns each and output file with data of 3 files in 6 columns

Comment: Tried to put that in for you - please correct if wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pr command with merge:

file1:

```
CELBU,398 
ORICE,1026 
JSCUN,134250 
BHARA,66 
MOBTE,2041 
RMO,65081
```

file2:

```
8/22/2013,1417196108
8/23/2013,1370586883
8/24/2013,1362561606
```

file3:

```
ISBND,9 
BHARH,25
```

Input:

```
pr -tm -s, file1 file2 file3 > new
```

Output:

```
CELBU,398,8/22/2013,1417196108,ISBND,9
ORICE,1026,8/23/2013,1370586883,BHARH,25
JSCUN,134250,8/24/2013,1362561606
BHARA,66
MOBTE,2041
RMO,65081
```

- -t, --omit-header omit page headers and trailers
- -m, --merge print all files in parallel, one in each column, truncate lines, but join lines of full length with -J
- -s separate columns by a single character

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pr.htm

Comment: By using Pr -tm its printing perfectly but when redirecting output to output.csv its appending columns of 3rd files just below the columns of second file :(
Be noted that all three files are csv files and have 2 columns but no. of rows in each file are different. If i use your command on files with same no. of rows then it works perfectly but in case no. of rows are different it appends file 3 just below where data of file 2 ends.

Comment: I am not sure how to paste in columns here please concider row change after name and value there are 2 columns in each file.



file 1:-
CELBU 398
ORICE 1026
JSCUN 134250
BHARA 66
MOBTE 2041
RMO 65081


file2:-
8/22/2013 1417196108
8/23/2013 1370586883
8/24/2013 1362561606

file3: 
ISBND 9
BHARH 25

Comment: yes it is but i think you are considering .txt files while i have .csv files.

Comment: yes, it worked fine for above case but for real case scenario it i had to change the sequence of files to be merged in order of no of lines in each file as pr -tm -s, file1 file3 file2 where no. of lines file1 > no. of lines file2 > no. of lines file3 if we take file with lesser no. of lines on 2nd no. then it will append data of 3rd file instead of adding it to new column. please cosscheck and veryfy the findings.

Comment: It shouldn't do. If you're separating columns by `,` then you'll get output like this line for file1 file3 file2: `JSCUN,134250 ,,8/24/2013,1362561606` Here, there is only data in columns 1 and 3 - and if you were to separate columns with tabs it would be easier to see. In your case, read `,,` as empty column.